# SqlAlchemy for SQL Geo data types for Python 3+

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using Python 3.3 with sqlalchemy using a MySql database. I know that mysql supports Geo data types, but I was unable to find the equivalent in sqlalchemy. I did see GeoAlchemy and GeoAlchemy2 but GeoAlchemy is not for Python 3 and I am not using a PostgresQL for GeoAlchemy2. Any packages/libraries that you would recommend to query all points in a bounding box? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution? thanks

Comment: Hi @Edi . http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html . See the Geometry example. It is exactly what you need!

Comment: Thanks! Does it work well with all GEO queries defined in sqlalchemy.func?

Comment: Hi @Edi, have you found out about any package/library to use SQLalchemy and MySQL for geo datatypes and functions?

Comment: @AfeezAziz I needed to make a single query which uses the GEO functionality so eventually I just executed raw SQL and parsed the results. Additionally, I used Redis GEO functions for fast GEO distance queries - if this is your use case then you can try it as well.